# How do I get value of cID on form submission

Tags: php, mysql

```
<img src="img/commentBelowIcon.png" width="26" height="26" class="left" /><h3>Add Comment</h3>
                <?php if(!empty($_GET['pID'])) $the_pID = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['pID']); $thedt = date("Y-m-d");?>                              
                <form action="inc/q/prof.php?pID=<?php echo $the_pID; ?>" method="post" id="addition">            
                     <div class="field required"> 
                    <select id="courseInfoDD"  class="verifyText" name="courseInfoDD" tabindex="1">
                    <option  disabled="disabled">Course...</option>
                            <?php while($row3 = $sth3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                                    {echo "<option value=". $row3['cID'] . ">" .$row3['prefix']." ".$row3['code']."</option>";}
                            ?>
                    </select>    
                    </div>
                     <div class="field required">    
                    <select id="commQuarter" class="verifyText" name="commQuarter" tabindex="2" >
                            <option  disabled="disabled">Quarter...</option>
                             <option value="Fall">Fall</option>
                             <option value="Winter">Winter</option>
                             <option value="Spring">Spring</option>
                             <option value="Summer">Summer</option>
                    </select> 
                    </div>
             <div class="field required"> 
             <select id="commYr" name="commYr" class="verifyText" tabindex="3">
                            <option  disabled="disabled">Year...</option>
                            <?php $startdate = 2000;$enddate = date("Y");$years = range ($startdate,$enddate);foreach($years as $year){echo "<option value='$year'>$year</option>";}?>
              </select>  
             </div>

            <div class="field required">    
                    <select id="commExp" class="verifyText" name="commExp" tabindex="4" >
                        <option disabled="disabled">Overall Experience</option>
                        <option value="1">Positive</option>
                        <option value="2">Neutral</option>
                        <option value="3">Negative</option>
                    </select> 
             </div> 


            <div class="field required">
                    <textarea type="text" id="addComment" class="verifyText" name="addComment" tabindex="5" value="Enter comment"></textarea></div>
                <input type="hidden" name="dt" value="<?php echo $thedt; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="pID" value="<?php echo $the_pID; ?>" />
                <div class="field required">
                Accept Terms?
                Yes:&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="terms" value="Yes" id="accepting" tabindex="6" />
                No:&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="terms" value="No"  id="accepting" tabindex="7" />
                </div>
                <p class="iferror">Please correct the above.</p>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="8" />
                </form> 

                    </div>
            </div>

<?php // Get select box options 
$pID3 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pID', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $pdo3 = new PDO('mysql:host=###;dbname=###', $u, $p);
        $pdo3->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sth3 = $pdo3->prepare('
    SELECT pID, C.cID, C.prefix, C.code
    FROM Department D, Course C, Professor P
    WHERE pID = ?
    AND D.dID = C.dID
    AND D.dID = P.dID; 
');
        $sth3->execute(array(
            $pID3
        ));
?>
```

I get submitted data that looks like this:
[image: img]

How do I get a value for `cID` to submit as well? Can someone show me what I need to put in my php?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the code that processes the form & updates the database? Would cID be the value of the courseInfoDD select box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

execute

```
$cid = mysql_insert_id();
```

after

```
$sth3->execute(array(
            $pID3
        ));
```

link http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

hope helps

:)